# How to aggregate on Year and Location?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am using Postgresql, I am trying to get Sales grouped by Location and Year,
I wrote this query which works fine

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT( YEAR FROM p.sale_datetime)::VARCHAR AS years,
    SUM( p.amount::BIGINT ) AS sales,
    l.name AS locations
FROM
    purchase p
INNER JOIN locations l ON
    p.loc_id = l.id
GROUP BY
    1, 3
ORDER BY
    1 ASC
```

This is the result I get

```
YEARS   SALES       LOCATIONS
2016    35338890    US
2017    19778097    UK
2017    115229473   Austria
2017    444444      Norway
2018    300212      US
```

But since US only has Sales for year 2016 and 2018, I dont see its sale for 2017. I need to see 0 Sales for US as well like

```
2017   0   US
```

Sorry for very generic Question as I  couldn't formulate words to describe the problem

Comment: Can you please share your table data too?

Comment: @GarimaGupta Both tables are pretty generic Purchase has 
**id, seller_name,sale_datetime, amount, loc_id(foreign key)**
and Locations just has **id, name**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically done using `generate_series()` to generate a list of years and then using an outer join. As you also want all locations, regardless whether they had sales or not, you need to create a cross join between the years and locations and then join that to the purchase table:

```
select t.years,
       t.name AS locations,
       sum(coalesce(p.amount,0)) as sales
from ( 
  select t.years, l.id as loc_id, l.name
  from generate_series(2016,2018) as t(years) 
    cross join locations l
) t
  left join purchase p 
         on extract(year from p.sale_datetime)::int = t.years 
        and p.loc_id = t.loc_id
group by t.years, t.name
order by t.years, t.name;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/NJDHXJ69904

Comment: Sorry I might be brain dead but I still am not getting Sales = 0 for location that has no record for that year,
I have even tried to add check for null **COALESCE(SUM(p.amount),0) **

Comment: @AnnasTelenor: `coalesce()` should work, see my online example

Comment: I might have had misled you. Actually your solution is fine but what I want is that each location should have aggregated sales for each year. Using your solution I wont be able to get location